# pandas appending df1 to df2 get 0s/NaNs in result

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. df1 comprises a Series of values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'winnings': cumsums_winnings_s, 'returns':cumsums_returns_s, 'spent': cumsums_spent_s, 'runs': cumsums_runs_s, 'wins': cumsums_wins_s, 'expected': cumsums_expected_s}, columns=["winnings", "returns", "runs", "wins", "expected"])
```

df2 runs each row through a function which takes 3 columns and produces a result for each row - specialSauce

```
df2=  pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda w,r,e: doStuff(w,r,e), df1['wins'], df1['runs'], df1['expected'])), columns=["specialSauce"])


print(df2.append(df1))
```

produces all the df1 columns but NaN for the df1 (and vice versa if df1/df2 switched in append)

So the problem I has is how to append these 2 dataframes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are a couple of things going on here.  You've left code out and I had to fill in the gaps.  For example you did not define `doStuff`, so I had to.

```
doStuff = lambda w, r, e: w + r + e
```

With that defined, your code does not run.  I had to guess what you were trying to do.  I'm guessing that you want to have an additional column called `'specialSauce'` adjacent to your other columns.

So, this is how I set it up and solved the problem.

#### Setup and Solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 6),
                  columns=["winnings", "returns",
                           "spent", "runs",
                           "wins", "expected"]).cumsum()

doStuff = lambda w, r, e: w + r + e

df['specialSauce'] = df[['wins', 'runs', 'expected']].apply(lambda x: doStuff(*x), axis=1)

print df.head()

   winnings   returns     spent      runs      wins  expected  specialSauce
0  0.166085  0.781964  0.852285 -0.707071 -0.931657  0.886661     -0.752067
1 -0.055704  1.163688  0.079710  0.155916 -1.212917 -0.045265     -1.102266
2 -0.554241  1.928014  0.271214 -0.462848  0.452802  1.692924      1.682878
3  0.627985  3.047389 -1.594841 -1.099262 -0.308115  4.356977      2.949601
4  0.796156  3.228755 -0.273482 -0.661442 -0.111355  2.827409      2.054611
```

#### Also

You tried to use [`pd.DataFrame.append()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).  Per the linked documentation, it attaches the DataFrame specified as the argument to the end of the DataFrame that is being appended to.  You would have wanted to use [`pd.DataFrame.concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: this is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks. The function doStuff isnt doing anything special so the lambda is perfectly OK. The confusing aspect for me was initially perhaps the assignment to a single column data frame specialSauce.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand things, your issue seems to be related to the fact that you get `NaN`'s in the result `DataFrame`.

The reason for this is that you are trying to `.append()` one dataframe to the other while they don't have the same columns.

`df2` has one extra column, the one created with `apply()` and `doStuff`, while `df1` does not have that column. When trying to `append` one `pd.DataFrame` to the other the result will have all columns both `pd.DataFrame` objects. Naturally, you will have some `NaN`'s for `['specialSauce']` since this column does not exist in `df1`.

This would be the same if you were to use `pd.concat()`, both methods do the same thing in this case. The one thing that you could do to bring the result closer to your desired result is use the `ignore_index` flag like this:

```
>> df2.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

This would at least give you a 'fresh' index for the result `pd.DataFrame`.

**EDIT**

If what you're looking for is to "append" the result of `doStuff` to the end of your existing `df`, in the form of a new column (`['specialSauce']`), then what you'll have to do is use `pd.concat()` like this:

```
>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

This will return the result `pd.DataFrame` as you want it.

If you had a `pd.Series` to add to the columns of `df1` then you'd need to add it like this:

```
>> df1['specialSauce'] = <'specialSauce values'>
```

I hope that helps, if not please rephrase the description of what you're after.

Comment: All DataFrames have indexes, defined or default, the series of numbers [0 ... n] that appear as the first column if you print a DataFrame is the default index. If you were to `append` or `concat` using `ignore_index=True` then you get a 'fresh' range for the result DataFrame. There is no way to not have an index in a `pd.DataFrame`, even if you don't define one you get one for free :)